# Creating a dummy indicating the last row of each group

Tags: stata

I have the following panel dataset.

I did

```
sort FirmID Year
```

to make the following.

```
FirmID    Year  
 1        1996
 1        1997
 1        1998
 2        2000
 2        2001
```

I want to create a new variable `exitnextyear` which is 1 if the firm does not exist next year, so that the output is

```
FirmID    Year   exitnextyear  
 1        1996      0
 1        1997      0
 1        1998      1
 2        2000      0
 2        2001      1
```

I think I have to use something like

```
by FirmID: gen exitnextyear (and something)
```

but I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clear 
input FirmID    Year  
 1        1996
 1        1997
 1        1998
 2        2000
 2        2001
 end 
 bysort FirmID (Year) : gen byte exitnextyear = _n == _N 

 list, sepby(FirmID)
```

For the principles, see help and manual entries on `by:` and/or a tutorial review accessible [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0004).

Row is spreadsheetspeak; in Stata the term is *observation*.